# How to get Active Records along with Inactive Records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  sample  Data  Set

```
ID   Name  Active 
1    Mii    0
1    Mii    1
2    Rii    0
2    Rii    1
3    Lii    0
4    Kii    0
4    Kii    1
5    Sii    0
```

How  I can get  active  records  along  with Inactive  records  for  other  ID's.

```
ID   Name  Active 
1    Mii    1
2    Rii    1
3    Lii    0
4    Kii    1
5    Sii    0
```

I have  taken all the  data  into 2  temp tables  because  lot of  joins  are  there

```
select  * from  tmp1  where  active  = 1  
UNION ALL
select  * from  tmp2  where  active  = 0 AND  
    NOT  EXISTS  (SELECT  1  FROM  tmp1   WHERE  Active  = 1 )
```

can anyone  tell me  is there any better way to write in MYSQL

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `active` can only be `0` or `1`, aggregation could help:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       max(active) active
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY id,
                name;
```

`max(active)` is `1`, if there is a record with the `id` and `name` that has a `1` in `active`, as `1 > 0`. Otherwise it is `0`, the only value.

Comment: simple  one  I have  made it  more  complicated ..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using analytical functions:

```
select * from (
SELECT ID, NAME, RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY ACTIVE desc) AS RN
FROM TABLE1) a where rn = 1;
```